# Non-associative ring whose non-zero elements form non-commutative quasigroup (with regard to multiplication) without identity?

Tags: ring-theory, division-algebras

An example of a *non-associative* ring R whose non-zero elements form *commutative* quasigroup (with regard to multiplication in R) without identity is easy to find.

I'm looking for examples of a non-associative ring S whose non-zero elements form a *non-commutative* quasigroup without unity.

Put another way: A non-associative non-commutative division ring without unity.
'division ring' in the spirit of 'ring R (associative or not) whose non-zero elements form non-empty quasigroup by means of multiplication in R'.

Can you help me ?

Comment: I'm not sure what quasigroup means, but what about taking an octonionic order and scaling by 2?

Comment: 'octonionic order' ?

Answer (score 1):

Let $(R,+,\cdot)$ be any non-associative division ring (including any field) - then $(R \setminus \{0\},+,/)$ is, in the general case, a non-associative non-commutative division ring without unity.

Comment: I believe that there is an error here: in any ring one should have *distributivity*, i.e. $x(y+z) = xy + xz$. But, in this case, $x(y+z)$ is in fact $x/(y+z)$, while $xy + xz$ is $x/y + x/z$, so distributivity fails.

Comment: My mistake, it's right distributive but not left, so my example would only be a division near-ring.

Comment: How do u define / ? Note that, in multiplicative quasigroup ʁ of R,  x=ya=by needn't imply a=b since multiplicative quasigroup is non-associative. So we have left-division and right-division.

Answer (score 0):

The ring $\Bbb O$ of Cayley octaves is indeed the example you want, because it contains Hamilton quaternions $\Bbb H$ as a subring, whose multiplicative *group* (w/o $0$) is already noncommutative. $\Bbb O$ is actually constructed from $\Bbb H$ via the Cayley-Dickson process.

Comment: Caution, ℍ has unity. I require non-zero elements to form a non-empty non-associative non-commutative quasigroup, which is not a loop.

Comment: Could you please provide the easy to find example in the beginning of your post..?

Comment: Yes, I can. Not intended though, because I'm looking for new approaches.

Comment: Not nearly an expert on this topic, but for example [this](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869313005589) paper is about 8-dimensional non-unital division algebras, and algebras from the main non-unital family (Section 3) contain an anti-commutative $P$... Might this be of help?

Comment: Wow, the article you are referring to is depressing. No two consecutive sentences I understand, or so.

Comment: In earnest, 'division ring' maybe more appropriate here. Though I never found a definition of division ring that satisfied me. For example, the definition on Wikipedia posits a ring with unity. That may be historically true, but is not my concept of division ring. I my world a 'division ring' is any ring whose non-zero elements form a non-empty quasigroup (its multiplicative quasigroup). It's unital iff the quasigroup is a loop.

Comment: Then I define 'skew field' as an associative division ring. Note that the multiplicative quasigroup of each associative divsion ring is a group ! You see, we don't need the concept 'module', let alone 'algebra', to work on my question.

Comment: Every alg. is a ring though :-) It's easier to work with alg-s than arbitrary rings, and they are better studied (incl. assoc. and Lie ones). WP has articles both for ["D. ring"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_ring) and ["D. alg."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algebra). The d. alg. WP page seems to contain the dfn. that suits your d. ring dfn., just for alg-s. As for $\Bbb O$, well, eq-s $a = ba$ have the same solution there, and thus every d. subring must contain it. Intuition, of course, suggests that "most" nonassoc. rings with some additional properties would be noncomm.

Comment: Every algebra is a ring ? Is every car ferry a car ?

Comment: Of course, for example, each commutative associative ring ℜ is both, a left- and right-algebra over ℜ. And each ring is a unital ℤ-algebra, mostly because each abelian group is unital ℤ-module. But my question is just ring-theoretic, and so should be the answer ?

Comment: unital as module, not necessarily as algebra....

Comment: A more appropriate question would be "Is every gun truck a car", since the whole difference between the concepts is that the former one satisfies an additional property (having a weapon installed, or having a bilinear structure).
You can just ignore the $k$-linear structure on your algebra and righteously call it a ring, which it will be even in the nonassociative case. (A rhetorical question: is Wedderburn—Artin a result on rings or algebras?) Or did you specifically want a ring that is not an algebra over a field? In that case, you should edit the OP, it is not clear from it at present.

Comment: The Wikipedia entry for division algebras indeed contains a hint to a solution of my question. But it is essentially buried in a flood of unnecessarily general additional statements.

Comment: Thank you for your attention, 'amateur'. I think we both know an answer to my question by now. But I insist that too much abstraction or just data has a dangerous potential for humankind.

Answer (score 0):

What the OP is looking is a noncommutative *presemifield*, and then a *semifield* is the case where there is a multiplicative identity element. Here is one of the two smallest examples, the other being given by the transpose of the table below.

On $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$ with its usual addition, define $(0,0)\cdot (x,y) = (0,0) = (x,y)\cdot (0,0)$ for all $x,y\in \mathbb{Z}_2$ and define all other products according to the following table:
$$
\begin{array}{c|cccc}
 \cdot     & (0,1) & (1,0) & (1,1) \\
\hline
(0,1) & (1,0) & (0,1) & (1,1) \\
(1,0) & (1,1) & (1,0) & (0,1) \\
(1,1) & (0,1) & (1,1) & (1,0)
\end{array}
$$
The nonzero elements evidently form a noncommutative quasigroup without an identity element. Nonassociativity is also easy to see:
$$
((0,1)\cdot (0,1))\cdot (0,1) = (1,0)\cdot (0,1) = (1,1) \neq
(0,1) = (0,1)\cdot (1,0) = (0,1)\cdot ((0,1)\cdot (0,1))\,.
$$
It's not obvious by inspection that both distributive laws hold, but this can indeed be checked.